# Latest update messes things up

Tags: updates, internet, display-resolution

Today I updated ubuntu (usual update, that shows authomaticaly every few days) and after restarting, I got weird resolution (smaller screen), no internet connection, almost no options in settings menu,…

I don't know what happened an how to get things back?

Maybe this was somehow connected: after update and befor restarting I changed kernel from 4.15.0-43-generic to 4.15.0-45-generic (see this thread: [Minecraft crashes, losing connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121651/minecraft-crashes-losing-connection/1121668?noredirect=1#comment1854682_1121668) )

UPDATE: it also doesn't wake up from hybernation

Ifconfig -a gives me just lo interface. I don't get my ethernet

Comment: We don't know either.

Comment: @Pilot6 Did you also face the same? Should we not update as of now?

Comment: No, I didn't face the same.

Comment: What happens if you boot back to an older kernel?

Comment: @heynnema: How to boot back to old kernel without internet access? I have RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller, which is not seen (Ifconfig -a). I don't seem to have instaled driver r8168, nor r8169.

Comment: @Mersault boot to GRUB menu, choose Advanced Options, select a kernel older than -45. See if your network returns. Also, show me `dkms status`. Report back to "@heynnema"

Comment: @heynnema return to -44 kernel makes things ok. Internet is back, also resolution. Dkms status gives me nothing. So should I install kernel -44 from Advanced options?

Comment: @Mersault -44 is already on your system. Where did you get -45 from? Normal Software Updates, or somewhere else?

Comment: @heynemma: I had kernel -45, but when I was trying solutions for other problem (see in my original post) I replaced it with kernel -43. As it did not solve problem, I replaced it back with kernel -45 (and I did that in between usual ubuntu updates with software updater and restarting system (updates needed restart)). So do I now have to start always from Advanced options? Normal ubuntu start brings me to broken -45 kernel.

Comment: @Mersault yes, for the short term, boot via Advanced Options, until they come out with a -46 kernel or newer, that solves the various symptoms.

Comment: @heynnema: thank you very much! Would you maybe know what to do in my other thread? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121651/minecraft-crashes-losing-connection/1121668?noredirect=1#comment1854682_1121668

Comment: @Mersault I've left a comment for you over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

When booting from -45 kernel, symptoms are "weird resolution (smaller screen), no internet connection, almost no options in settings menu, and hibernation problems".

Booting to the prior -44 kernel and all of these symptoms were cured. For the short term, continue to boot to this kernel to maintain full system operation. (note: -44 kernel may have an issue with console ttys).

Monitor `Software Updater` for -46 or newer kernel updates, then boot to them and see if symptoms are also gone.